# AWS Elasticache Redis version with StackExchange.Redis

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, amazon-elasticache

Which version of AWS Elasticache Redis is the StackExchange.Redis client SDK compatible with?  Can it support Redis 4.0 which AWS offers?

I've not been able to find an answer to this question.